# Ubuntu 20.04 Subiquity Install - Point to Local Apt Repo on Iso

Tags: apt, 20.04, iso, subiquity

I am working on fully automating an installation of Ubuntu 20.04.4 server using the subiquity autoinstall method.  I have a successful configuration that installs unattended, and pulls in the ubuntu-desktop-minimal, gnome-session, and gdm3 packages during installation.  My understanding is that it is getting these packages from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu during the installation.

However, I have a need for this installation to occur without any network connection.  I have an aptly repository that I can package on the iso, and I'd like to point the apt configuration in the autoinstall file to this repo instead of the main Ubuntu repos.

Is this possible?  If so, what would the syntax look like in the apt section of the autoinstall config file?

Thanks!  Happy to clarify anything if needed!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract the image , and inject the apt repository into image and repackage.

change apt source  to :

deb [check-date=no] file:///cdrom/PATHOFAPTLYREPO jammy main restricted

remember to have the associated gpg key added to the environment